# How do you activate a venv in atom?

Tags: atom-editor, python-venv

I'm new to all of this and I've been following tutorials the best I can, I wanted to try my hand at web app development but I'm clearly doing something or missing something.

I ran pip install Django in my Atom terminal, it said the installation was successful but threw a warning about my install file not being part of the PATH, even though that file is in fact on PATH but I believe I fixed that issue.

I then tried to follow a Django tutorial which told me to pip install venv, I couldn't get that to function but I did find the virtual environment package on Atom  atom-python-virtualenv and installed it.

its there in my drop down package menu but when I click make and enter a name nothing happens.

I have been trying repeatedly to figure out how to activate a virtual environment in my atom terminal since last night and nothing seems to work! I tried the same commands in my windows powershell and they worked perfectly fine, so I went back to Atom and within that powershell tried again and the first couple things worked but I still ended up with an error which I'll copy/paste below;

```
PS C:\Users\Amelia\Documents\Atom Projects\microblog> cd env:
PS Env:\> ls virtual_env
ls : Cannot find path 'virtual_env' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls virtual_env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtual_env:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemN
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemComm
   and

PS Env:\> cd c:

PS C:\Users\Amelia\Documents\Atom Projects\microblog> .\venv\Scripts\activate
.\venv\Scripts\activate : The term '.\venv\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\venv\Scripts\activate:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong here, the venv files are there in my script file if I look but nothing I do seems to allow them to be activated.

All I want to do is learn how to do this stuff and I can't get it to work. This is the first issue I've run into so far and I'm at a total loss as to how I might fix this.

is venv just completely incompatible with Atom??

I'm running Windows 10 if that helps in anyway.

Comment: what versions of Python have you loaded?

Comment: Do not use the Mac preintalled version of python?!  How did you install python?  Homebrew, Anaconda, Python.org?

Comment: I'm running Python3, I grabbed it off Python.org.

Comment: I'm on Windows not Mac so I'm not using the Mac pre installed version :)

Comment: The problem might be the  .  as the first character in the directory name.  Virtual environment command should create a directory with the name you gave it.

Comment: yea sorry about Mac comment. I didn't see that you used Windows till later. Sorry.

Comment: you can try creating your virtual env. from the command line using "virtualenv mypython"

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try that when I get back on my computer and let you know how it goes! I've been fighting with it since last night so it would be great to have it just work haha

Comment: guys?  lol..   your welcome.

Comment: Haha oh sorry! I thought there was two usernames there  my bad!

Answer (score 6):

My friend, first of all you have to select a specific folder for your project in a certain way in your system.
Then create a virtualenv via cmd on that path..[image]

[image]

Now I'm activating my virtualenv via cmd
[image]

Now I'm inside my Virtualenv, I can log in if Atom is installed on my system

[image]

Now in the Atom software, at the bottom left of the screen, press noVirtualenv.
A window opens where your Virtualenv name is displayed, and you can select it by tapping on it.

[image]

Now your Virtualenv is ready and you can create or import your own project and get started.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can activate virtual environments from the command line by typing

```
mypthon\Scripts\activate
```

where mypython is the name you gave to your virtual environment. This assumes the Atom extension correctly created the virtual environment.

Comment: I'll have to try this, I'm not sure if atom is creating the virtual environment though because when I click make and type in a name nothing happens, the bottom corner just says no virtual environment selected and if I click that there is no options there to choose from.

Comment: i tried creating a virtual environment using Atom and it worked fine. But you can't define which version of python to associate with the environment.